# On the GitHub tags page, how can I easily go to the last page?

Tags: github

For example, on Linux`s tags page, https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tags, there are over 700 tags.

Sometimes I want to find the middle one or the oldest one, but I have to click the `Next` button a lot of times.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

I've tried guessing the value of the `after` parameter, like [https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tags?after=v3.0] (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tags?after=v3.0), but still, it's a lot of work to navigate to the last page.

Answer (score -1):

Last page: From the main page of the repository (Code tab) expand master branch (Switch branches/tags), switch to Tags tab, scroll to the end and copy one of the tag names.
Go to Releases/tags page, click on next and replace the string in the "after=" part of the url.

Middle page: similar principle, but copy the tag name somewhere in the middle.

It could be more complicated than that (especially for the middle, if tags have different name styles), for ex. https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc - the last tags aren't the latest, but the names of release tags are easy to determine (they start with "release").